# How do I use `Explain` with a `find_by_sql` query?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

`User.find_by_sql("...my statement here...").explain`

results in an error `undefined method explain for array`... which makes perfect sense to me...

I'm not using rails. I'm using `sinatra` although that should not matter since the commands come from the `activerecord` gem which I am using...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not directly run explain in the sql, this is one time activity, right??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error is pretty self-explanatory.

You can **only** run `explain` on `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects. But `find_by_sql` gives you an `Array` instead, on which `explain` cannot be called.

You have two ways to work around this:

1. Convert your query with `ActiveRecord` methods (which return
   `Relation`)
2. Use `explain` inside your `find_by_sql` string.